Nuxt 3 - Props are not reactive or update properly when modified in parent component
I'm working on a Vue.js application and have encountered an issue where the tasks in a list (submissions) are not updating reactively when modified within the parent component. I have a SubmissionWrapper component that updates the tasks array, but the changes don't reflect in the SubmissionInfo or SubmissionTask components without an external trigger.
Here's a simplified version of the code:
Submission Wrapper
<template>
   # Other template code
     <GraderSubmissionInfo 
         v-for="(submission, index) in submissions"
         :key="index"
         :submission
     />
</template>

<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    let submissions = ref([]);
    let isCreatingSubmission = ref(false);

    async function createSubmission() {
        if (isCreatingSubmission.value) return;

        isCreatingSubmission.value = true;

        let taskCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        let tasks = Array.from({ length: taskCount }, (_, index) => ({
            status: 'undf',
            title: `Task ${index + 1}`,
            scoreEarned: 0,
            scoreTotal: 20,
            notes: `Notes for Task ${index + 1}`,
        }));

        let submission = {
            title: 'Attempt',
            scoreEarned: 0,
            scoreTotal: 20,
            submissionTime: new Date().toUTCString(),
            duration: 503,
            status: 'undf',
            tasks,
        };

        submissions.value.unshift(submission);

        for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000 + Math.random() * 10));

            tasks[i].status = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'pass' : 'fail';
            tasks[i].notes = 'updated';

            submissions.value[0].tasks = [...tasks];
        }

        isCreatingSubmission.value = false;
    }
</script>


Submission Info
<template>
     <div>
        <div>
            <GraderSubmissionTask 
                v-for="(task, index) in submission.tasks"
                :key="index"
                :task="task"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

Submission Task
<template>
    <div class="bg-secondary px-8 py-2 flex flex-row items-center justify-between font-mono">
        <div class="flex w-[50%] items-center">
            <div class="pr-8">
                <component 
                    :is="activeComponent"
                />
            </div>
            <div class="">
                {{ task.title }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-[25%]">
            {{ task.scoreEarned }} /{{ task.scoreTotal }}
        </div>
        <div class="w-[25%]">
            {{ task.notes }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { defineProps } from 'vue'

    const props = defineProps({
        task: Object
    })

    const stateComponents = [
        'Progress',
        'Failed',
        'Success'
    ]
    let activeComponentKey = ref(stateComponents[2])


    const activeComponent = computed(() => {
        return defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`~/components/Icons/Small/${activeComponentKey.value}.vue`))
    })
</script>

The issue:

The tasks array within submissions is updated asynchronously in the createSubmission method, but the changes don't automatically propagate to the child components (GraderSubmissionInfo and GraderSubmissionTask).
I tried using submissions.value[0].tasks = [...tasks]; to trigger a reactivity update, but it doesn't seem to reflect in the DOM unless I trigger an external update.
I suspect the issue might be with how Vue handles reactivity in this case, possibly related to how I'm mutating the tasks array or the way components are being passed data.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated

Index is not a good key for v-for and should be avoided (it's practically the same as using no key at all).  It should work better if for the <GraderSubmissionTask> v-for you use :key="task.notes" so when the notes property is mutated the diff is detected and the node rerenders. However, keys should be unique, so if task.notes are not unique you can create a key that uses notes plus some other unique property. You may want to add an id property to your tasks for this purpose.
let tasks = Array.from({ length: taskCount }, (_, index) => ({
  id: index,
  status: 'undf',
  ...
}))

<GraderSubmissionTask
  v-for="task in submission.tasks"
  :key="task.id + task.notes"
  :task="task"
/>

If you plan on changing other properties besides tasks you will need to make sure the v-for key in the SubmissionWrapper component is also something better than just index. Key must always be a string, number or symbol, so at the very worst you could stringify the entire submission object, :key="JSON.stringify(submission)" or create a string from one or more properties.
